# Using wildcards in combination with exact match in the r library Elasticsearch

Tags: r, elasticsearch

Likely due to my inexperience in Elasticsearch (and the R library Elastic), I cannot figure out how to formulate a search query in such a way that an exact match is combined with a wildcard.

```
docs_create(index="test",type="x", body=list(txt="this is a test"))
count(index='test', type='x',q="'a test'",default_operator="AND")
```

... returns one match.

```
count(index='test', type='x',q="'a te*'",default_operator="AND")
```

... returns no match (although I hoped to get one match too).

```
count(index='test', type='x',q="'a te/*'",default_operator="AND")
```

... produces an error (`Error: 400 - all shards failed`).

```
count(index='test', type='x',q="'a te'//*",default_operator="AND")
```

... returns no match.

Any help is welcome! Thank you.

PS. If this is impossible using the count function, using the Search function is fine too to solve my issue (using the body parameter).

Comment: what version of `elastic` and Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: I use version 5.4.0

Comment: okay, which version of `elastic` (the R pkg)?

Comment: The latest too, version 0.7.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a great week of sleep, I figured out how to get this done (using the `match_phrase_prefix` option:

```
docs_create(index="test",type="x", body=list(txt="this is a test"))

body <-
'{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix" : {
            "txt" : {
                "query" : "a te",
                "max_expansions" : 10
            }
        }
    }
}'

Search(index='test',body=body)
```

Answer (score 0):

@peterk what does the query without the single quotes return?

Can you try it like this:

```
count(index='test', type='x', q="a te*", default_operator="AND")
```

Comment: @usogan, yes that returns one hit, but does not solve the problem as 

`count(index='test', type='x', q="is te*", default_operator="AND")` 

returns a hit too which I do not want.

In the Elasticsearch documentation I saw the option `prefix search`, maybe that's the beginning of the solution?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note, try `connect(errors = "complete")` to get more verbose errors - basically the same info the elastic server gives

```
count(index='test', type='x',q="'a te/*'",default_operator="AND")
#> Error: 400 - all shards failed
#> ES stack trace:
#> 
#>   type: query_shard_exception
#>   reason: Failed to parse query ['a te/*']
#>   index_uuid: xbZ5ANNBRwqxEsqPqS05Dg
#>   index: test
```

Which suggests that that query is not valid

In general it's easier to use `elastic::Search()` as its more flexible - and set `size` parameter to 0 so you just get a count of records matched.

It's still not clear to me what is the exact part. Is it `a te` or `a test` or something else?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; okay I switch to `elastic::Search()`.

Sorry for being unclear, what I want get back / find in the database are all phrase combinations that start with the (exact part) `a te`, including `a te`, `a test`, `a tests`,  `a testies`.

Hope my question is clear now.

Comment: did you try yet wildcards with the query DSL https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html via `elastic::Search()`  - does that do what you want?